# Not display the someone phone number location

Tags: android

How to display the others mobile number location?

```
Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);  
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
result = sb.toString();
```

The above code displays only address location, not the mobile number location

Comment: What are you asking? What is a mobile number location?

Comment: others mobile number location of longitude and latitude from the server

Answer (score 0):

Whilst an address is static a phone number is not.

You will not be able to get the location of a mobile phone number at all.

Many counties have dialing codes that would allow you to determine a very rough location of a phone number (0207 for central London for example) but that is country specific and you would have to obtain lists for your intended markets.